# XPages : how to add custom attributes to ressources added via a theme

Tags: xpages

I would like to add defer or asyn attribute to JS and CSS ressources loaded via theme.

If I load them via an XPages ressources tag I can do something like that

```
<xp:script src="/.ibmxspres/domino/..." clientSide="true">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="defer" value="1" minimized="true" />
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:script>
```

But how to do this in an XPages theme ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply adding it to the theme to see if that works?

```
<resources>
    <script src="/.ibmxspres/domino/..." clientSide="true">
        <this.attrs>
            <attr name="defer" value="1" minimized="true" />
        <this.attrs>
    </script>
</resources>
```

Worth a try, eh?